# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement while trying to save son values in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I know it's an old question and I have found a lot of answers but none of them are working. I really need help.

I am decoding some JSON and then need to update my db with the new values.

```
$id = $_POST["user_id"];
$facebook = $_POST["facebookId"];
$userInfos = $_POST["userInfos"];

$json = json_decode($userInfos, true);

        $coins = $json['coins'];
        $score =  $json['score'];
        $highest_coins = $json['highest_coins'];
        $upgrades = $json['upgrades'];
> line 89
        $sql = "UPDATE app_user SET coins = ?, score = ?, highest_coins = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        $stmt->bind_param('iiis',$coins,$score,$highest_coins,$id);
        $nb = $stmt->execute();
line 99
            foreach(is_array($upgrades) as $person => $value)
            {
                $character_id =  $value['character_id'];
                $upgrade_id =  $value['upgrade_id'];
                $upgrade_level =  $value['upgrade_level'];

                $sql = "UPDATE user_upgrades SET upgrade_level = ? WHERE facebook_id = ? AND character_id = ? AND upgrade_id = ?";
                $stmt->bind_param('isii', $upgrade_level, $facebook, $character_id, $upgrade_id);
                $nb = $stmt->execute();
            }
```

> Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement on line 89
>
> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 99

I really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: put `$upgrades` instead of `is_array($upgrades)`.

Comment: yes you're right but I'm still having the biggest problem. 
What's the matter with number of variables

Comment: may be data you are passing that does not match datatype `isii`

Comment: i checked them by using the function gettype() on each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a variable called `$sql`, but do not use it. We do not see how you initialized `$stmt`. You need something like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

applied to your case:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE app_user SET coins = ?, score = ?, highest_coins = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('iiis',$coins,$score,$highest_coins,$id);
    $nb = $stmt->execute();
```

and in your `foreach` get rid of the `is_array`, which returns a `boolean` from your `array`.

Comment: i didn't pay attention to the prepare statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

is_array($upgrades) returns bool, you need array there

Comment: You're right it works fine i'm still getting number of variable doesn't match.

Comment: which line is that now?

Comment: let`s see what var_dump($coins,$score,$highest_coins,$id); outputs

Comment: int 0

int 200

int 100

string '8DQDk6raDGTHAxEieMWl1444308985' (length=30)

Comment: Maybe try $stmt->bind_param('iiis', 1,$score,$highest_coins,$id);

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```